# How to fix the Python and JSON Delimiter Expected Error?

Tags: python, json

I'm entering the following code and receiving the delimiter expected error. From what I can gather JSON Decoder wants a ',' automatically inserted between each record I pull from the For Loop. I can't seem to find any solution. It pulls one record from the URL, then stops.
Line 1, Column 54 (char 53) does not appear to exist.
There are 9 columns on line 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import urllib.request


sample = pd.read_csv('Codes.csv')

with open('FilmList2.json', 'r+') as filmlist:
    data = json.load(filmlist)


def compare():
    for code in sample:
        code = urllib.parse.quote(code)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(f'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i={code}&type=movie&apikey=71c66a81') as url:
            entry = json.load(url)
            data.update(entry)
            with open('FilmList2.json', 'a') as filmlist:
                json.dump(data, filmlist, indent=4, separators = (', ',': '))       

compare()
```

[image: Error Message]
[image: Missing Delimiter]

Comment: Is this a URL we can read too? Simply the example to one canned URL that demonstrates the problem. We don't care about codes.csv or enumerating all of them. Remove that part to focus on the issue.

Comment: Okay, so you aren't going to give us a URL to work with. Can you at least give us the first 100 characters of the response? The error says there is a problem on the first line, 53rd character. You've shown us what could be a different problem on line 44 where it appears that you have two separate JSON records. That could be solved using `json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode()` called multiple times until the data is consumed. But it appears you have a problem before that.

Comment: Sure, sample URL: http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0120902&type=movie&apikey=71c66a81

Comment: That particular example worked for me without a decode problem. Maybe `print(code)` before the json.load would find the bad one.

Comment: It will pull one, It won't pull multiples, it locks up as soon as it's time to write the second entry.     Example, try entering this as the CSV.  tt0120902,
tt1132620,
tt1216487,
tt1343097,
tt1568346,
tt5177088,
tt0848228,
tt9242528,
tt0053768,
tt16290354,
tt0081383,
tt0926129,
tt0084695,
tt14449392,
tt0046534,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, JSON format delimit each element with an `,` so if your file is not properly formated, the `json` package will not works.

This does not works so it will raise an error:

```json
{
  "name": "paul"
  "age": 18
}
```

But this works fine (because it is properly formatted):

```json
{
  "name": "paul",
  "age": 18
}
```

So, you just should gather the data from the file, store it in a variable, update the variable with the new data (it's what your doing).

But then, don't append the content to the file, re-write it with the new value (on line 19, use `"w"` instead of `"a"`:

```py
with open('FilmList2.json', 'a') as filmlist:
    json.dump(data, filmlist, indent=4, separators = (', ',': '))
```

Comment: I put it in a JSON validator and reformatted it. Fixed it. Suspected same as you, formatting error somewhere in the near 37k lines.